# pip install whl file off-line without network

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install off line the python pkgs - `argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` as the following

```
pip install --ignore-installed --no-index --find-links /pkgs/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant "pip install /pkgs/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl"?)
```

but the installation failed on - `Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simpleIgnoring`

what is the right way to install off-line ( without network internet ) the `whl` file - `argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

we run the pip on `rhel 7.x` machines with `python 2.7`

*we also tried the following but other error appears and without success*

```
pip install --ignore-installed --no-index --find-links /pkgs argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

seems that the direction to the right syntax is

```
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links="/pkgs" "argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

but when I add the flag  `--ignore-installed` as

```
pip install  --ignore-installed  --use-wheel --no-index --find-links="/pkgs" "argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

then we get

```
exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 587, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 798, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 705, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/pkgs/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason you need to ignore installed.
I don't know the exactly what causes the problem, but pip cannot see the file you are trying to install

some things that could be wrong:

Did you look if the file still exist after

> pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links="/pkgs" "argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3 none-any.whl"

and it can be accessed by a command without root privilege.
Another reason for your problem could be that

> --ignore-installed

forces pip to not use the file